# TypeORM - returns double result

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, typeorm

I have a problem with search by querybuilder in typeorm:

```
const projects = await this.conn.getRepository(UserProjectRelations).createQueryBuilder('userProject')
            .innerJoin("userProject.userId", "user", "user.id = :userId", { userId: user.id })
            .innerJoinAndSelect("userProject.projectdId", "projectdId")
            .addSelect(['userProject.id', 
                            'userProject.status', 
                           ])
            .getRawMany();
```

why when i launch this query, in result i get an double rows like `id` and `userProject_id`?

output below:

```
{
    "userProject_id": 1,
    "userProject_status": "Owner",
    "status": "Owner",
    "id": 1
}
```

i want to return only this two objects:

```
{
    "status": "Owner",
    "id": 1
}
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you use getRawMany() it returns the raw data that you mentioned: `userProject_id` and `userProject_status`

What if you tried using getMay() instead. I think that if you do you will get the object in the shape that you desire. Which will be {id, status} only

```
const projects = await this.conn
  .getRepository(UserProjectRelations)
  .createQueryBuilder('userProject')
  .innerJoin('userProject.userId', 'user', 'user.id = :userId', {
    userId: user.id,
  })
  .innerJoinAndSelect('userProject.projectdId', 'projectdId')
  .addSelect(['userProject.id', 'userProject.status'])
  .getMany(); // Try this instead of getRawMany()
```

Get Raw will return raw data and give you more than you wanted. Its good for generating fields that don't exist on the entity, for example using sum or avg on some other field value.

Here is some further reading on getting Raw data:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-raw-results